flutter IntrinsicHeight with Column
in my Column i want all children have the height of maximum height of the children.
i could do it for width with IntrinsicWidth, in Column. but IntrinsicHeight is not working in Column. here is my code:
// IntrinsicHeight + Column
// flutter IntrinsicHeight not working with Column
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('IntrinsicHeight + Column'),backgroundColor: Colors.blue,),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.amber[50],
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: List.generate(5, (i)=>Container(width: (i+1)*10, height: (i+1)*10, color: Colors.green, margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

does IntrinsicHeight work in Column?

I'm afraid that's not gonna work. Although I'm not entirely sure why it wouldn't work. I think it has something to do with Columns telling their children they have limited width but unlimited height. Like in your case it will tell its children they can only be 300 width but they are not telling them about the 500 height. This available height will only be considered when using Expanded or Flexible children. There probably is a way to get what you want but it might require a complex solution.

How about replacing height: (i + 1) * 10 with: height: 5 * 10 ?

@MHMD, the problem is childrens max height is dynamic, it can be other than 50.

Can you calculate the max height of the children before building the UI?

Yes IntrinsicHeight works with Columns.
To make the height of the children in a Column be as the height of the tallest one you have to:
Wrap the Column with IntrinsicHeight and the children with the Expanded widget.
Explanation:

The IntrinsicHeight widget will ensure that all children in the Column will take up the height of the tallest child.

The Expanded widget ensures that all children will expand equally to take up the available space provided by IntrinsicHeight.


here is a code showing that:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        //brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 10,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Text('Short widget'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Text('tall widget'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 10,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Text('Short widget'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Here is your code edited to make the widgets equal in height:
note:

I have removed the height of the Container, so the Column & Container takes only the height of the children.

// IntrinsicHeight + Column
// flutter IntrinsicHeight not working with Column
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('IntrinsicHeight + Column'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          //height: 500,
          color: Colors.amber[50],
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: List.generate(
                5,
                (i) => Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: (i + 1) * 10,
                    height: (i + 1) * 10,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I hope that helps.

thank you for the solution. another question, does IntrinsicWidth work with vertical ListView.builder ?
